# How to use Dracula theme as a style in Pygments?

Tags: pygments

I can not understand documents about [Pygments Styles](https://pygments.org/docs/styles/#creating-own-styles), which says:

> To make the style usable for Pygments, you must
>
> 1. either register it as a plugin (see the [plugin docs](https://pygments.org/docs/plugins/))
> 2. or ... put it into the file mondrian.py and this file into the pygments.styles subpackage directory.

Now there is already a [Dracula theme for Pygments](https://draculatheme.com/pygments), how can I add it as a new pygments style, so that I can use the style by a simple command line (E.g. `pygmentize -g xx.py`).

Either by registering a plugin, or puting `dracula.py` in to the `pygements.styles subpackage directory` (where it is?). I just don't know how to do this, and there is not a single example.

PS: My OS is ubuntu-18.04 and I install pygments by `sudo apt-get install python-pygments python3-pygments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me (also Ubuntu 18.04), the path of the installation directory is: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pygments`. There you will find another directory named `styles` where all the existing color themes are present (e.g. autumn.py, fruity.py). You may create your own style (following: https://pygments.org/docs/styles/) and store the corresponding style file here.

I hope this partially answers your query.

Comment: Thanks very much. I installed pygments by "sudo pip3 install pygments" and my directory is "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pygments/styles". I copied "dracula.py" to this folder and modified \_\_init\_\_.py, then the new style is available by "pygmentize -P style=dracula -g"

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it working (assuming pygmentize already installed).

1. Run `echo hello | pygmentize -P style=does_not_exist` which will output an error which includes the `styles` directory.
2. Navigate to the `styles` directory.
3. Download the [Pigments Dracula theme](https://draculatheme.com/pygments), unzip and copy `dracula.py` into the `styles` directory.
4. test `echo "const result = 'success';" | pygmentize -P style=dracula`, hopefully the result was Dracula themed!

I'm using MacOS & pygmentize installed through homebrew.